# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::post()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, query-builder

I have a problem with using the query builders that give me the undefined method error for using `post()` in the routes file.

Usually I use the return of

```
User::find($id)->post;
```

but when I call `post` as a function, it doesn't work and gives me:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::post()

**User Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{


  protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
 ];

 protected $hidden = [
     'password', 'remember_token',
 ];


 protected function post()
 {       
     return $this->hasOne('App\Post');  
 }

 }
```

**Routes**

```
  Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('welcome');
  });



  Route::get('/user/{id}/post',function($id){

  return User::find($id)->post()->get();    

  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The post() method in your User class needs to be public. Right now it's protected, which means outside classes can't access it.
>   ~ @jackel414

As Jackel414 mentioned your `post()` function is protected and needs to be public for you to access it.

I noticed that you're running the `get()` function on a one to one relationship, this function is designed to bring back a collection of data unless you pass an id as the parameter, it's best practice to use the examples below:

```
return User::find($id)->post;
```

Or

```
return User::with('post')->find($id);
```

Alternatively you may bring back the builder to expand your queries even further.

```
return User::find($id)->post();
```

Answer (score 3):

The `post()` method in your User class needs to be public. Right now it's protected, which means outside classes can't access it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/user/{id}/post',function($id){

   return User::with('post')->find($id);    

});
```